# Live Updating Frosted Glass UI jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I need a frosted glass UI effect, which is basically a transparent, white div overlaying some content. The part of the content beneath the div should be blurred. The effect should look something like this:
http://codepen.io/Matori/pen/JFzok

```
random code because StackOverflow forced me to add it
```

The problem is, I'm not using any background images. My app is a drawing tool, where the user can draw shapes and text. So the area over which the frosted glass div will be overlayed, will be updating every second.

I've tried [this html5 Canvas plugin](http://abduzeedo.com/ios7-frosted-glass-effect-html-5-and-javascript) but I couldn't get it working. Anyway, would it suffice? Or does it just take a snapshot of my body element on page load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's one way to do the effect.**

- Apply a fast blur (by Mario Klingemann) to your image,
- Overlay a "frost" made by a white rectangle at 25% opacity.

The blur script is here: http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html

[image]

Example code and a Demo:   http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/PA9NC/

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
    img.onload = start;
    img.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/Dog-With-Cute-Cat.jpg";

    function start() {
        canvas.width = img.width;
        canvas.height = img.height;

        // draw the image

        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

        // blur the image with blur radius=10

        stackBlurCanvasRGB("canvas", 0, img.height/2+30, img.width, img.height / 2, 10);

        // draw a white rectangle at 25% opacity

        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.25;
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        ctx.fillRect(0, img.height/2+30, img.width, img.height / 2);

        // draw some text at 40% opacity

        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.40;
        ctx.font = "102px arial";
        ctx.fillText("Us", 225, 275);
    }
```

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I don't have any images. There are no images anywhere in my web app. I need to make this work with website content (divs, text, inputs buttons etc.) which will be live updating every second. For example, imagine Facebook wanted to give their blue header bar a frosted glass effect. So as the header scroll over the page content (which live updates), the content can be seen blurred beneath the bar. How would they do it?

Comment: Ouch! You said "My app is a drawing tool, where the user can draw shapes and text ... overlaid with the frosted glass" and you included the "canvas" tag, so I assumed you have control of the content underneath.  If not, you will probably have to downgrade to overlaying a fixed semi-transparent white image over your content.  If you don't control the content, you can't do a blur effect.

Comment: A fixed transparent image would be no different to a transparent white background color though, right? I thought it might be possible to take a snapshot of the document every second, then use that as the image or something?

Comment: Yes, a semi-transparent overlay of "frost" would not be as satisfying without the blur effect on the content. Perhaps add some "noise" to the frost? It's important to control the content so that you can get access to the content's pixels. The blur effect is created by altering pixels, so without access to the pixels the blur effect is not possible. Currently, it's not possible to get a reliable snapshot of a web page unless you satisfy the cross-domain security requirements. And this security cannot be satisfied unless you control the content.

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/p38rswyc/) is the same effect with a moving background image.